# passing function argument to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following piece of code, I want to pass `delta` argument into the function being called by `fadeOut`, without having to set a variable outside the scope of those functions. Is it possible?

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    $('#view img').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.view-loading').fadeIn('fast');
        showcase.rotate(delta);
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't the variable `delta` already available to the inner function via the closure in your example?

Comment: you have it accessible in the scope so what is the point of providing argument to your callback?

Comment: @SeanVieira no, I get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually define the delta with the jQuery "mousewheel" event

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    event = event.originalEvent;
    var delta = event.wheelDelta;
    $("#view img").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.view-loading').fadeIn('fast');
        showcase.rotate(delta);
        showcase.fillRect(100, 10, 150, 100);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't really work out what the deal is with jQuery and `mousewheel` (it's late, I'm tired), but using jQuery 1.9.1, I can get a `delta` from the `originalEvent` property of the event object (which is in scope within your inner function. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bdx6K/1/)).

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    $('#view img').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.view-loading').fadeIn('fast');
        showcase.rotate(event.originalEvent.deltaY);
    });
});
```